# How to restore the online payment link after payment for contribution failed?

Tags: contributions, payment, user-dashboard

An online payment for a pending contribution failed and the contribution is now set to status = failed.
The result is that the constituent's dash board has the status failed for that contribution and the link to make a payment is gone. The constituent cannot make an online payment.

In CiviCRM, as administrator, I cannot change the contribution status to pending.The contribution status dropdown list only offers:  Failed, Overdue, Partially paid, or Pending refund.  I want to choose Pending.
Although it wold not be correct, I decided to try to choose "Overdue" but received this error message "Cannot change contribution status from Failed to Overdue."

How can we reset this so that the constituent can make an online payment?

Comment: how about changing the status of the contribution to pending?

Comment: CiviCRM does not allow us to change it to pending.   That is the problem.